# FlashAirのLua機能で現在日時は取得できませんよね？

Tags: flashair, lua

はじめまして！
FlashAirをお試しで使っています。
Luaでftpを使用してサーバーからファイルをダウンロードしたのですが、ファイル日時が登録されません。
当然かと思いますが、FlashAirには時計はなく現在時刻を取得する方法は無いですよね？

外部ネットワーク接続で、ネット上の現在日時を取得できないとしてですが。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

APIのドキュメントにOS機能は使えないとありますので、現在時刻を取得する方法はありません。

https://flashair-developers.com/ja/documents/api/lua/

> ### 制約事項
>
> メモリ制約のため、標準ライブラリの以下の機能は使用できません。
>
> - コルーチン操作
> - OS機能
> - 数学関数
> - デバッグライブラリ